# jQuery form validation alert

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, alert

I have this jQuery validation control in my form. It's working:

```
$("#webform-client-form-45").submit(function(){

  if($("#edit-submitted-name-surname").val() == "" || $("#edit-submitted-name-surname").val() == "Name Surname"){

        return false;
    }else if($("#edit-submitted-telephone").val() == "" || $("#edit-submitted-telephone").val() == "Telephone"){

        return false;
    }else if($("#edit-submitted-e-posta").val() == "" || $("#edit-submitted-e-posta").val() == "E-MAIL"){

        return false;

    }else{  if($("#edit-submitted-messages").text() == "" || $("#edit-submitted-messages").text() == "Message"){

                return false;
            }else
        return true;
    }
});
```

But when the user leaves the field empty or write's wrong in this fields, i want to show an alert. For example, "Please enter email address""

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an alert box:

```
if($("#edit-submitted-name-surname").val() == "" || $("#edit-submitted-name-surname").val() == "Name Surname")
{
alert("Please input your name");
return false;
}
```

Using divs:

//html

```
<input type = "text" name = "edit-submitted-name-surname" id = "edit-submitted-name-surname" />
<div class = "error" id = "name_error">Please input your name</div>
```

//css

```
.error{ display: none; color: red;}
```

//jquery

```
Put this at the top of the function: $('.error').hide();

if($("#edit-submitted-name-surname").val() == "" || $("#edit-submitted-name-surname").val() == "Name Surname")
    {
    $('#name_error').show();
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want alert windows, its must seen text view.